# How to put fullcalendar in jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I need a help to put full calendar (taken from [arshaw.com/fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) agendaview calendar) in a jquery dialog, which will popup on an image click.

I am bit confused about the jquery dialog with calendar.

Comment: What is your confusion exactly? Have you tried anything?

Comment: thank you, ihave seen that link, there only i have justreplaced the form content div with the calendar div. nothing is displaying in onclick.

Comment: ok edward, i will try and let you know thank u

Answer (score 0):

check in the following URL will solve your 
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`jQuery UI dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) as "standard usage" and inside it define a jQuery fullcalendar.

In the following code:

1. I initiate a fullcalendar control on the object `myCalendar`
2. I initiate a jQuery UI dialog  on the object `myDialog`
3. On the click event of a button I open the dialog (anche than the calendar)

The init of the control is wrapped in the document.ready function:

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

HTML:

```
<button id="openDialog">Open dialog</button>
<div id="myDialog">
    <div id='myCalendar'></div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#openDialog").button().click(function () {
        $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
    });

    $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                var day = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'dd'));
                var month = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'MM'));
                var year = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'yyyy'));
                alert(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
            });
        },
        editable: true,
        events: [{
            title: 'event1',
            start: '2011-05-07'
        }, {
            title: 'event2',
            start: '2011-05-10',
            end: '2011-05-15'
        }, {
            title: 'event3',
            start: '2011-05-07 12:30:00',
            allDay: false // will make the time show
        }]

    });

    $("#myDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true
    });

});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M3qGM/

Comment: i have tried what u told, its displaying button but onclick of that nothing is happening. When I tried previously, I was facing the same problem. Is it the problem of external links. I have included those things.

Comment: Works for me on jsfiddle; if you have a specific problem post it and ask to reopen the question...any errors in console?